# Create elements in script#

Tags: script#

In my javascript code I'd like to make a new form, add hidden items to it and submit the form without the form ever having to have been real on the page.

I can do this in javascript but can't write it in script# as the FormElement constructor is internal. Is there some other way I can acheive this as I'd really like to use Script# to do this.

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create elements using Document.CreateElement, just as you would with Javascript, then cast the result to the specific element type you just created.  For instance:

```
FormElement f = (FormElement)Document.CreateElement("FORM");
// ...
// Assign properties of f
// ...
Document.Body.AppendChild(f);
```